# How to pass object through GET http param

Tags: html, angular, http

Im trying to send the object Pack through get like:

```
  save_pack(Pack: any){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      this.http
        .get("http://localhost:8000/save_pack?Pack="+Pack)
        .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res);
          },
          (err: any) => {
            reject(err);
          }
        )
    });
  }
```

However, when I try to check if the value of that object is correct into my API rest, for example  checking it size, I get just an undefined instend of the value of the size of the object.

```
app.get('/save_pack', async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    const Pack = req.query.Pack;
    console.log("Size de Pack en peticion" + Pack.size)

    let result = await save_pack(Pack);
    res.send(result)
    return res;

})
```

Im I doing something wrong? Im not sure if an object should be send like this.

Comment: You should use the overload to pass query string parameters so you are ensured the value is properly encoded: `this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/save_pack", {params: {Pack:Pack.toString()}})`

Comment: That way, I get exactly the same error.

Comment: I am reading your question as you are trying to send the value `3` in the query string assigned to `Pack`. Is that correct?

Comment: No, what I want to do is to send the object Pack so I can use it in my API Rest.

Comment: This is a perfect illustration of why it is important to include [mcve] with your question so there can be no mistake about what it is you are trying to do. It is difficult to guess what values are assigned or being passed based on the code you have shown above.

Comment: Ok, Im going to include all the relevant code.

Comment: To your question though you can't pass an object using a http `get` request because an http get request does not support an http body. You have several options: 1. dont, instead just pass the atomic values you need. 2. change the request type to Put or Post which do support a http body 3. manually serialize the value you want to pass to a string and then pass that and deserialize it on the server. you can pass it in a http header or query string parameter.